# Callable example behaves different in debug mode in java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, callable

I'm testing the java.util.concurrent.Callable and implemented the call() in the class below but when using the isDone() of Future class, It doesn't evaluate to true and never prints the string in print statement but when debugged the same it did evaluate to true and prints. Why does it behave different. Thanks in advance.

```
public class CallExample implements Callable<String>{

    public String call(){
        return "h";
    }   
    
    public static void main(String k[])throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException{
        CallExample call=new CallExample();
        Thread one=new Thread();
        ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<String> fut=service.submit(call);
        if(fut.isDone()){
            System.out.println("Im here");   // Prints only in debug mode 
            System.out.println(fut.get());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Because in debug mode the callable has had time to run...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you just trying to wait for the `Future` to complete?

Comment: @AndyTurner- Yes, completing the task and print it from isDone() method

Comment: @assylias- correct, debug mode was only for some 5-10 seconds(which printed it) but i left the execution as it is for 45 seconds in normal execution(there is no shutdown called on the pool) to see if that gets printed but it does n't. Thats the point here.

Comment: @Raken change `if (fut.isDone())` to a `while` and you will see the output. When the `if` is reached in normal running mode, the future is not done yet, so the execution moves to after the `if` block and terminates main. But you have some threads running in the background (the executor) which prevent your program from exiting.